# When Trying to Import Old Visual FoxPro Database into SQL receiving "Cannot find column -1"

Tags: sql-server-2008, importerror, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I have a ton Visual FoxPro db files that I am trying to import into an empty SQL 2008 Express database.  When I run through the SQL Import and Export Wizard everything seems to communicate fine.  When I get to the mappings section I can click on preview and see the data in the selected FP table.  When I click on Edit Mappings or Next I get:

```
===================================
Column information for the source and destination data could not be retrieved.

"eqr_sellers" -> [dbo].[eqr_sellers]:

           - Cannot find column -1.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
===================================

Cannot find column -1. (System.Data)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Data.DataColumnCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls.ProviderInfos.MetadataLoader.LoadColumnsFromTable(IDbConnection myConnection, String[] strRestrictions)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.DtsWizard.OLEDBHelpers.LoadColumnsFromTable(MetadataLoader metadataLoader, IDbConnection myConnection, String[] strRestrictions, DataSourceInfo dsi)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.DtsWizard.TransformInfo.PopulateDbSourceColumnInfoFromDB(IDbConnection mySourceConnection)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.DtsWizard.TransformInfo.PopulateDbSourceColumnInfo(IDbConnection mySourceConnection, ColumnInfoCollection& sourceColInfos)
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the data types?  Auto-Increment Integer fields are not supported by the ODBC connectors I have used in the past.

Comment: Hmm This might be it then.  The keys on all of the tables are ints and most likely auto increment.  I actually found a free app that will do the importing for me.  It is located here

http://www.brothersoft.com/ms-sql-server-foxpro-import-export-download-55162.html